# Check if float number is in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to check if a float is in a dataframe column.
See this code:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [24.02, 149, 123.11]
imp = 149.0

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['List1'] = list1
```

If I run:

```
imp in df['List1']
>> False
```

I expected to get `True` in return ... How shall I improve my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` of a Series checks whether the value is in the index, if you want to check if value is in values use `x in df['List1'].values`

```py
import pandas as pd

list1 = [24.02, 149, 123.11]
imp = 149.0

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["List1"] = list1

print(1 in df["List1"])
>>> True
print(imp in df["List1"].values)
>>> True
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> (pd.Series([24.02, 149, 123.11]) == 149.0).any()
True
```